# Creating report/dashboard on json data

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I have questionnaire web app(uses ReactJS framework) deployed on google cloud run. questions and answers are saved in Cloud SQL (Postgres) table column as json format (key,value pair) as below:

```
{"Email Address":"xyz123@gmail.com","Name":"Shubman","How did you find us":"Web search","Capital":200000,"Instruments":["Convertible","SAFE"]}
```

When creating report in Data Studio, above json format is not exploded as individual key and value , instead it is treating whole json format as single. but I want to build report after extracting key value pair to individual column(s). How to do it?.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Studio can't do this for you (actually, maybe it can with REGEX, but it doesn't really worth the effort), but you can make a query in Cloud SQL/PostgreSQL to explode this JSON in separated columns.

Suppose your table is the following (notice the json field called `my_json`):

```sql
create table dumb_table (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100), my_json json);
insert into dumb_table (id, firstname, lastname, my_json) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein', '{"customer": "Lily", "items": {"product": "Beer","qty": 46}}');
insert into dumb_table (id, firstname, lastname, my_json) values (2, 'isaac', 'newton', '{"customer": "Josh", "items": {"product": "Milk","qty": 77}}');
insert into dumb_table (id, firstname, lastname, my_json) values (3, 'marie', 'curie', '{"customer": "Mary", "items": {"product": "Soda","qty": 88}}');
```

You can explode them in individual fields as follows:

```sql
select
   /* get all fields */
   dumb_table.*

   /* explode the remaining JSON fields */
   , dumb_table.my_json ->> 'customer'           as customer_name
   , dumb_table.my_json -> 'items' ->> 'product' as product_name
   , dumb_table.my_json -> 'items' ->> 'qty'     as quantity
from dumb_table;
```

This way, Data Studio doesn't need to parse your JSON field.